# App crashed while integrating stripe view payment gateway in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe payment gateway in xamarin.android but I have get application closing issue. Here is the sample code what I have tried.

Sample Code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PaymentView), typeof(CardInputActivity)]
namespace SampleProject.Droid.PaymentController

public class CardInputActivity(Bundle bundle) : Activity
{
  base.OnCreate(bundle);

  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CardInput);

  Helper.StripeView = FindViewById<StripeView>(Resource.Id.stripeLayoutOne);
 }
```

CardInput.axml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="20dp">
<Stripe.StripeView
    android:id="@+id/stripeView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code I have tried. In above 'CardInPutActivity' is the renderer class in android, 'CardInputView' is the layout file in resource folder and 'PaymentView' is the portable class contain view.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not sure what the answer is. It appears the Xamarin Stripe component is several years old now, and may not work any longer. This component was built by Xamarin themselves[1], so contacting them for help may be your best bet.

Beyond that I'd try to go step-by-step through your application with a debugger and/or add some `System.out.println()` statements to see where things are falling down.

[1] https://components.xamarin.com/view/stripe